# Python modify generator

Tags: python, generator

I implemented a (simple) python generator. Now, I want to make another one (from it), which will iterate through all values, but last one.

```
def gen(x):                   # Generate the interval [x, 10]
    if x <= 10:
        yield x
        for v in gen(x + 1):
            yield v
```

What would be the best way to accomplish that? Is it possible to alter the original generator using a decorator?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code.  You probably can't just modify existing directly, but you probably can generalize what you have to be able to work for both cases.

Comment: I'll add my code, but I still believe knowing it is a generator is all you need for the answer.

Comment: `itertools.islice` is good enough for this

Comment: How can we tell you how to modify what you have to do what you want without knowing what you have already?

Comment: @AlexeyKachayev: No it is not. `islice()` does not support negative indexes. You'd have to know up front how many items the other iterator will produce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a temporary variable as a simple "queue", you can forward elements from any iterator and keep the last one at the end:

```
def islice_to_last(it):
    prev_value = next(it)
    for value in it:
        yield prev_value
        prev_value = value
```

or more generally (for generators up to **x** last elements):

```
from collections import deque
import itertools as it

def islice_without_end(it, x):
    d = deque(it.islice(it, x))
    for value in it:
        yield d.popleft()
        d.append(value)
```

Comment: How about the decorator part, does it make logic?